# Non-ssh password for Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am setting up my ansible playbook to configure my servers to authenticate through Windows AD rather than the local authentication system. I everything is working except when I run

> net ads join -U myusername

This command requires that I type in myusername's password, which is different than the ssh and sudo passwords. 
Is there a way to either store a password in vault and have ansible grab it for that command?
If not, is there a way to have ansible prompt me for the password rather than just crash so I can type it in manually? T

Answer (score 2):

You can supply the password to `net ads join` like this:

```
net ads join -U <username>%<password>
```

Store the password in an ansible vault file, then use it in the Ansible task using the `shell` or `command` module as usual.